# Consulta eloquent con relacion belongsTo y hasMany (laravel-datatables)

Tags: laravel, datatables, eloquent

Bueno estoy teniendo problemas para **mostrar datos de mi relación** con **datatables**. 
La informacion que quiero visualizar se relaciona de la siguinete manera:
tengo la tabla clientes, pedidos y detalles:
**un cliente puede  tener de 1 a N pedidos.
un pedido le pertenece a un cliente.
un pedido puede tener de 1 a N detalles.
un detalle le pertenece a un pedido.** 
Aca mi relaciones en el modelo pedidos:

```
class OrderNote extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [ 'num_order', 'status', 'date', 'finished_date'];

    public $timestamps = true;  

    protected $dates = ['date', 'finished_date'];    

    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
    }  

    public function details()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OrderDetail::class);
    }
```

mediante esta consulta:

```
$ordenes = OrderNote::with('client', 'details')->get();
```

recibo el siguiente error: **Property [name] does not exist on collection instance.**

mi controlador OrderNote:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\OrderNote;
use App\Client;
use App\OrderDetail;
use DataTables;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class OrderNoteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

        return view('admin.orders.index');
    }

    public function dataTable()
    {
        $ordenes = OrderNote::with('client, details')->get();

         // $ordenes = OrderNote::with('client', 'details')->get();
        // $ordenes = OrderNote::with('client')->select('clients.*');       
        // $ordenes = Client::first()->orders()->with('client');


        return dataTables::of($ordenes)
                ->addColumn('id', function ($ordenes){
                    return $ordenes->id;
                })  
                ->addColumn('fecha', function ($ordenes){
                    return $ordenes->date->format('d-m-y');
                })
                ->addColumn('cliente', function ($ordenes){
                    return
                        '<i class="fa fa-user"></i>'.' '.$ordenes->client->name_client."<br>".
                        '<i class="fa fa-phone"></i>'.' '.$ordenes->client->phone_client;                       
                }) 
                ->addColumn('producto', function ($ordenes){
                    return 
                            '<i class="fa fa-industry"></i>'.' '.$ordenes->details->name."<br>".
                            '<i class="fa fa-phone"></i>'.' '.$ordenes->details->code."<br>".
                            '<i class="fa fa-globe"></i>'.' '.$ordenes->details->description;

                })
                ->addColumn('estado', function ($ordenes){
                    return $ordenes->status;
                })                                              
                ->addColumn('accion', function ($ordenes) {
                    return view('admin.orders.partials._action', [
                        'clientes' => $ordenes,
                        'url_show' => route('admin.orders.show', $ordenes->id),
                        'url_edit' => route('admin.orders.edit', $ordenes->id),
                        'url_destroy' => route('admin.orders.destroy', $ordenes->id)
                    ]);
                })

                ->addIndexColumn()   
                ->rawColumns(['fecha', 'cliente', 'producto', 'estado', 'accion'])                
                ->make(true);          
    }
```

por ultimo mi script en mi vista index:

```
<script>
        $('#datatable').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: "{{ route('orders.table') }}",
            columns: [
                {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
                {data: 'fecha', name: 'fecha'},
                {data: 'cliente', name: 'cliente'},
                {data: 'producto', name: 'producto'},
                {data: 'estado', name: 'estado'},               
                {data: 'accion', name: 'accion'}                
            ]
        });
    </script>
```

creo que mi error esta en la consulta con eloquent. **Necesito realizar una consulta que involucre una relacion belongsTo y una relacion hasMany
de que manera podria resolver esto???**

Comment: Si un pedido tiene N detalles, la consulta te devolverá un pedido con una colección de detalles, por lo que para acceder a un atributo de un detalle, no podrás hacerlo directamente sobre la colección, deberás acceder primero a un detalle y luego a uno de sus atributos

Comment: No termino de entenderte podrías darme un ejemplo. ? Modifique mi consulta $ordenes =Client:::with (orders,  orders.details)->get () luego voy a la ruta de mi tabla y veo las relaciones del cliente pedido detalle como accedo a eso q me indicas anteriormente ?

Comment: Me refiero a cuando haces `$ordenes = OrderNote::with(''details')->get()`, luego no podrás acceder directamente a `$ordenes->details->name`, porque `details` es una colección, no un objeto.  Tendrás que acceder a cada detail en la colección para obtener uno de sus atributos

Comment: Podes probar haciendo un loop sobre $ordenes->details. `@foreach($ordenes->details as $detail) ...`